# Can IBM IHS server support more than one Websphere Application Server plug-in location?

Tags: apache-2.2

We want http://webserver.com/foo to point to an instance of WAS 6.0, and http://webserver.com/foo2 to point to an instance of WAS 7.0, running on the same server, but with different port numbers. This is a temporary thing, as we need to have both servers running as we transition our applications from running on 6.0 to 7.0.

The webserver is IBMIHS (an Apache variant), and it needs to use the WebSphere plugin to connect to the WAS servers.

Will this work? Any drawbacks?

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the plugin-cfg.xml on each appserver and then merge both and copy it to the IHS location. I had a similar setup with different app servers that handled different uri's

Answer (score 0):

You might need WAS 7 version plugin on IHS server and edit it manually.

Comment: It worked for me under was 6.x guess there is no need for WAS 7